# PHP - know characters failed in a preg_match function

Tags: php, preg-match

There is a method to know which characters does not match a preg_match function?
For example:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', 'Hello World!');
```

Is there some function to know the incorrect char, in this case spance and "!"?

---

Thanks for your replies, but the problem in your examples is you don't indicate the begin and the end of the string. Your examples works with string contained in another one and not with the string that is exactly like I defined in the pattern.

For example, if I had to validate the italian fiscal code of a subject, composed by a string formatted like this:

```
XXX XXX YY X YY X YYY X (X = letter, Y = number - without spaces)
```

which pattern is:

```
'/^[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{1}$/i'
```

I must validate the string that match exactly what I defined in the pattern.

If I use your code and I wrong 1 (only 1) character, the whole string was returned as error.
http://eval.in/9178

The problem of the reverse pattern occurs in a complex pattern, where are inserted the AND or the OR.

What I want to know is why the preg_match fails and not only if it fails or not.

Comment: I answered too fast so I deleted the answer. Are you tryin' to find the characters that do not match the regex, or are you tryin to find a regex that matches Hello world! ?

Comment: In this case you could match the reverse, something like `[^a-z]` (don't add the 'startofstring' obviously. But there is no general method to find where it didnt' work

Comment: I want to find the characters that do not match the regex, to help user to insert the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$nonMatchingCharacters = preg_replace('/[a-z]/', '', $wholeString);
```

That should strip out the 'legal' characters, leaving only the ones that you want to mention in your validation error message.

You could also do other treatments like...

```
$nonMatchingCharactersArray = array_unique(explode('', $nonMatchingCharacters));
```

...if you want an array of unique, non-matching characters, and not just a string with bits stripped out of it.

Comment: The limit of your solution is when the pattern of the regex inlcude size (for example `'/^[0-9]{11}$/'`) or a specific format (for example `'/^[0-9]{2}[a-z]*$/'`). In these cases your code returns the whole word instead only the "bad" characters.

http://eval.in/9146

Comment: In that case there are no 'bad characters', only bad strings ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That will indicate you the space and !

```
preg_match_all('/[^a-z]/i', 'Hello World!', $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

http://eval.in/9132

Comment: Use the reverse match is easy for the simple pattern, but when I have a complex one is more difficult.
Hello World! and its pattern is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove everything that matches with preg_replace, then split into an array what remains.

```
<?php

$str = preg_replace('/([0-9]{2}[a-z]*)/i', '', '03Hello 02World!');

$characters = str_split($str);

var_dump($characters);
```

http://eval.in/9152